# Why is my jQuery is not append in select option?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to append data in select option
but it's not showing/append in it

The AJAX works perfectly, but the append is fail

```
<select class="form-control show-tick" style="font-size: 14px;" id="office_code" name="office_code" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="choose" disabled selected>-- Choose Office --</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control show-tick" style="font-size: 14px;" id="kode_kantor" name="office_code" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="choose" disabled selected>-- choose office --</option>
</select>
```

This is the AJAX code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'http://x.x.x.x/test/API/getOfficeBySearch',
    'method': 'POST',
    'data': {
      'request': JSON.stringify({
        "username": "test",
        "password": "test",
        "searchparam": "type",
        "searchvalue": "office"
      })
    },
    'success': function(result) {
      result = JSON.parse(result)
      result.data.forEach(function(value, index) {
      var element =`<optionvalue="${value.officeid}">${value.name}</option>`
        $('#office_code').append(element)
      })

    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: you need to provide more information, which part not success we also dont know. Ajax fail or Append Fail?

Comment: the ajax works perfectly, but the append is fail

Comment: Could you add an example of the data returned by the ajax call?

Comment: Is `JSON.parse` really required?

Comment: see your `console` for errors ,also if your are returning `json` you need to put `datatype: 'json'` in ajax call and you have also missed to put `;` at end of statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing space, replace `<optionvalue` with `<option value`.